# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: —-header

Tags: json, rest, curl, watson-conversation, watson

This is my Command and i'm using Mac os,

```
curl -X POST \
-u "{username}":"{password}" —-header "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{\"input\": {\"text\": \"Turn on the lights\"}, \"context\": {\"conversation_id\": \"1b7b67c0-90ed-45dc-8508-9488bc483d5b\", \"system\": {"dialog_stack":[{"dialog_node":"root"}], \"dialog_turn_counter\": 1, \"dialog_request_counter\": 1}}}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/25dfa8a0-0263-471b-8980-317e68c30488/message?version=2016-09-20"
```

When i apply this the error log is,

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: —-header
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Content-Type
{"error":"Unsupported Media Type"}
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  solve theese problems by using this code

```
curl -X POST -u "CONVERSATION_USERNAME":"CONVERSATION_PASSWORD" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d "{\"input\": {\"text\":\" \"}}" "https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/CONVERSATION_ID/message?version=2016-07-11"
```

Answer (score 6):

In your `—-header` option the first character isn’t a normal hyphen (U+002d). Instead it’s an em dash (U+2014). Change it to a normal hyphen and things should work as expected.